# FB Graph application working one day not the next on /me response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I developed an application and it worked perfect, but today I get this error on /me request object using the JS API:

> "unknown error (empty response)"

This is very odd to me and I'm finding it hard to debug. Everything was working as intended the other day but today I get this strange issue, no code changes have happened. Any suggestions on how I can debug this?

Just a standard (This is done after user successfully Auths on my application with correct scope):

```
 FB.api('/me', {fields: "email"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response);      
 });
```

Result:

> error_subcode: 1357045 message: "unknown error (empty response)"

As mentioned this worked as intended the other day. Now for some strange issue it's not working and the only error I get is that as mentioned above.

This is called after user auths on my app with whatever scope I require.
As I mentioned this is very strange to me, nothing has changed at all on my side. Normally an object would be returned containing FB user ID and email.

Comment: There are a couple of current bug reports for this already, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/183138545796069/, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/794347400765683/

Comment: hmm so its a facebook issue ?

Comment: This happens with me as well time to time. There is nothing we could do about it and ended up adding retry mechanism in our jobs because it ends up working after few hours. Its more like a facebook issue. (I use Java FB sdk though)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in the past days and after some tests I found out what was the problem for me.

Change this:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: "email"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);      
});
```

with this:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: "id,email"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);      
});
```

Seems that the field **id** is mandatory...however I haven't found any official resource about this, this is the result of self made test.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a fix for me... how strange, i wonder what they have changed.

Comment: I also added the status field in the FB init:
`FB.init({
      appId: xxx,
      version: 'v2.11',
      status: true
    });`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a browser extension that is blocking your request. Try disabling any browser extensions and try again.